# How does JIT know where to look for csc.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, jit

How does JIT know where to look for csc.exe? Also how is this handled by other .NET languages, like IronRuby?

Comment: Just a misunderstanding about what each compiler does, that's all. If everyone knew everything to start with, SO would be an empty site.

Comment: @Jon: Exactly, I don't get the negative people on here. If one isn't willing to provide useful information, please don't waste anyone's time by making us read useless fluff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`csc.exe` compiles C# source code to MSIL. The JIT compiler is part of the CLR and is implemented in `mscorjit.dll`, which is located with the current CLR (2.0 atm).

Answer (score 8):

csc.exe produces IL code. JIT produces machine code from the IL code, so correct me if I am wrong but I don't think JIT has anything to do with csc.exe

Comment: But isn't stuff compiled on the fly by jit compiler, using the appropriate language compiler?

Comment: @Joan: No, the language compiler is C# to IL, the JIT compiler is IL to native code.